# What does the colon mean when defining a js function?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm just learning to make JavaScript games using Phaser and have a question.

I don't understand what the colon means when defining a function. For example:

```
attackEnemy: function(player, ground) {

}
```

And how is it different to doing it like this...

```
function attackEnemy() {

}
```

Comment: The first example is when you assign something to an object. It doesn't have to be a function. Read up on JavaScript objects to get a better idea of what is going on. Check the "Using object initializers" section of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `attackEnemy:`, you are not doing it outside. You should be doing it inside an object, say:

```
var game = {
  attackEnemy: function(player, ground) {

  },
  otherProperty: value
};
```

An object can have `function` as a member as well. This is how you define functions in the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use colon syntax when defining a key for object, like this:

```
var object = {
    attackEnemy: function(player, ground) {
    }
}
```

When you want define a function as separate element, you can do that (Function Declaration):

```
function attackEnemy() {
}
```

or that (Function Expression):
    var attackEnemy = function() {
    }

Comment: So when you use the colon, are you effectively assigning the function to attackEnemy?

Comment: You can use colon only when assigning the function to some key of object.